# How to get kubernetes node name and IP address as dictionary in ansible?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I need to get node name and IP address of each node and then create dictionary object.  I am able to get Kubernetes node list using below command

```
 - hosts: k8s

  tasks:
  - name: get cluster nodes 
    shell: "kubectl get nodes -o wide --no-headers | awk '{ print $1 ,$7}'"
    register: nodes

  - debug: var=nodes

  - set_fact:
      node_data: {}  

  - name: display node name
    debug:
      msg: "name is {{item.split(' ').0}}"
    with_items: "{{nodes.stdout_lines}}"

  - set_fact:
      node_data: "{{ node_data | combine ( item.split(' ').0 : { 'name': item.split(' ').0 , 'ip' : item.split(' ').1 }, recursive=True) }}"
    with_items: "{{ nodes.stdout_lines }}"

  - debug: var=node_data
```

I got below error:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected
>   token ',', got ':'. String: {{ node_data | combine ( item.split(' ').0
>   : { 'name':item.split(' ').0 , 'ip': item.split(' ').1 },
>   recursive=True) }}"}

Output of kubectl command given below

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide --no-headers | awk '{ print $1 ,$7}'
```

is as follows

```
> ip-192-168-17-93.ec2.internal 55.175.171.80
> ip-192-168-29-91.ec2.internal 3.23.224.95
> ip-192-168-83-37.ec2.internal 54.196.19.195
> ip-192-168-62-241.ec2.internal 107.23.129.142
```

How to get the nodename and ip address into dictionary object in ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the `combine` filter must be a dictionary. You're calling:

```
  - set_fact:
      node_data: "{{ node_data | combine ( item.split(' ').0 : { 'name': item.split(' ').0 , 'ip' : item.split(' ').1 }, recursive=True) }}"
    with_items: "{{ nodes.stdout_lines }}"
```

You need to make that:

```
  - set_fact:
      node_data: "{{ node_data | combine ({item.split(' ').0 : { 'name': item.split(' ').0 , 'ip' : item.split(' ').1 }}, recursive=True) }}"
    with_items: "{{ nodes.stdout_lines }}"
```

Note the new `{...}` around your first argument to `combine`. You might want to consider reformatting this task for clarity, which might make this sort of issue more obvious:

```
    - set_fact:
        node_data: >-
          {{ node_data | combine ({
            item.split(' ').0: {
              'name': item.split(' ').0,
              'ip': item.split(' ').1
            },
          }, recursive=True) }}
      with_items: "{{ nodes.stdout_lines }}"
```

---

You could even make it a little more clear by moving the calls to `item.split` into a `vars` section, like this:

```
    - set_fact:
        node_data: >-
          {{ node_data | combine ({
            name: {
              'name': name,
              'ip': ip
            },
          }, recursive=True) }}
      vars:
        name: "{{ item.split(' ').0 }}"
        ip: "{{ item.split(' ').1 }}"
      with_items: "{{ nodes.stdout_lines }}"
```